# MySQL inserts row even if disconnected

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm writing a C# application where I insert values into Mssql and Mysql tables.There is no problem with Mssql.If Mssql server disconnects it doesn't insert the value into Mssql table.

But in Mysql if Mysql server disconnects during Insert operation the value is sometimes inserted.MysqlException is caught in case of Mysql server disconnect but the value is inserted sometimes.

Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
try
{
    mysqlConn.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
    command.Connection = mysqlConn;
    command.CommandText = //INSERT INTO TABLE
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}catch (MySqlException ex){
     Console.WriteLine("MYSQL Exception: " + ex.Message);
}catch (Exception ex){
     Console.WriteLine("MYSQL Exception: " + ex.Message);
}finally{
    mysqlConn.Close();
}
```

How can I ensure that the value is inserted into Mysql table only if there is no disconnection during the operation and not inserted if there is disconnection during the operation?

Comment: I'm surprised the connection would be lost very often in the time it takes to run a simple insert, and that it will still insert if it disconnects. Maybe putting the insert into an explicit transaction will help. Otherwise, you may need to select data afterwards to check it was added correctly?

Comment: @Rhumborl I'm running batch files from C# to disconnect Mssql and Mysql on different intervals at random times to test if the program works even if databases disconnect.If Mysql is disconnected during operation it doesnt rollback insert operation but with Mssql I haven't encountered any problem.I have tried selecting the data after insert operation but still if there is disconnection during select operation it wont work correctly.Do you mean I should write transaction in Mysql and call it from C# so that Mysql handles disconnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding unique key to a field in Mysql database so that no single row can be inserted more than once.